# Update with Pymongo boolean field in a subdocument within a list field of a document in a MongoDB collection

Tags: mongodb, dictionary, mongodb-query, pymongo

## Example Database

Below is the collection of an example database:

```json
{
  {
    "_id": "fijo_1"
    "Procesos": [{
        "code_a": "1234",
        "code_b": "5678",
        "code_c": "9012",
        "vector_aux": ["01", "02"],
        "leido": false
    }, {
        "code_a": "0000",
        "code_b": "1111",
        "code_c": "2222",
        "vector_aux": ["03", "04"],
        "leido": false
    }  
    }]
  },
  {
    "_id": "fijo_2"
    "Procesos": [{
        "code_a": "3333",
        "code_b": "4444",
        "code_c": "5555",
        "vector_aux": ["01", "02"],
        "leido": false
    }, {
        "code_a": "6666",
        "code_b": "7777",
        "code_c": "8888",
        "vector_aux": ["03", "04"],
        "leido": false
    }  
    }]
  }
}
```

## Problem

I need to update or change the value of a specific field of a document that is hosted in an array position that is itself a field of a dbdd document.
More specifically, I need to change the field ***"leido"*** to ***True*** of the ***proceso number 2*** of ***"Procesos "*** for the ***"_id "*** named ***fijo_2***, by fulfilling a filter, corresponding to match **"code_a" with "3333", "code_b" with "4444" and "code_c" with "5555"**, being a **filter that fulfils several conditions**.

## Programming language and libraries:

I use Python 3.9 and the "pymongo" library as well as the base created in MongoDB.

## Problem Solved by [YuTing](https://stackoverflow.com/users/16695245)

Here is my code that now works:

```py
filter_aux = {'_id': "ES0031104316853001ED_1389"}
updtae_aux = {'$set': {"Procesos.$[element].leido": True}}
array_filters_aux= [{'element.codeA': "C1", 'element.codeB': "01", 'element.codeC': "000000000051", 'element.leido': False}]
collection.update_one(filter=filter_aux, update=updtae_aux,upsert=True, array_filters= array_filters_aux)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `$arrayFilters`

```
db.collection.update({
  "_id": "fijo_2"
},
{
  $set: {
    "Procesos.$[element].leido": true
  }
},
{
  arrayFilters: [
    {
      "element.code_a": "3333",
      "element.code_b": "4444",
      "element.code_c": "5555",
      
    }
  ],
  upsert: true
})
```

[mongoplayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/1aRp6bKmuPt)